# How to setup action on Google API on local server?

Tags: node.js, chatbot, actions-on-google

I am new for action for Google, and I want a help. I want to create a chatbot and wanna use actions on Google API for this, I came across certain blogs but I can not understand how to setup this thing and local and make use of actions on Google API's in a productive way. I have read the documentation but nothing seems to be work in a desired manner. Please help me with initial steps where I could begin with.

Comment: The video that @Raghav gave you is excellent. If you wish to read a tutorial with code, please check: https://medium.com/google-developers/build-your-first-smart-bot-for-google-home-18949f74822c 
or try this code lab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-action-on-google-with-webhook/#0

Comment: Thanks for your Reply @IdoGreen. Surely, I will watch that video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read the documents properly. Here's the correct address for developing actions :- https://developers.google.com/actions/apiai/ 
This is the perfect document, if you will use API.ai. If you want to learn faster then you have to watch videos. Here is the link for the basic video.

This is the basic video you need to watch :- https://youtu.be/5Al0bfCF-xA

I think this video will help you alot. If still you need some more help for building apps, do reply we will help !

Comment: Thanks @Raghav. I will surely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it on your local server by opening up a port on your wifi router and and forward that port to you server ip and port. However, you still https call from api.ai to your local server.